# JavaScript Accordion Text Swap

Tags: javascript, accordion, swap

I am trying to work with an accordion. My goal is to have a '+' symbol showing when not expanded and a '-' when expanded. I am just trying to get the first swap to work and cannot get the .equals() function to compare properly. Any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceMe(){
var symbol = document.getElementById("swap1").innerHTML;
if(symbol.equals("+") {
    document.getElementById("swap1").innerHTML="-";}
else { 
    document.getElementById("swap1").innerHTML="+";}
}
</script>
```

THIS IS THE HTML

```
<div class="accord">
<div class="title" onclick="replaceMe()">
    <h2 id="swap1">+</h2>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="desc">Sample Sample Fill Data</div>

<div class="title">
    <h2 id="swap2">+</h2>
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="desc">More Fill Data Not Important</div>

<div class="title">
    <h2 id="swap3">+</h2>
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="desc">Boring Filler Information</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JavaScript, not Java; you can safely use just `'==='` here to compare strings. ) And your `if` should really be `if(symbol.equals("+"))` - a closing parenthesis is missing in the code you quoted.